# SQL server service broker usage with ASP.net cache?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, caching, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I have  ASP.net site (4.5) which uses sql cache notification. (using  *`aspnet_regsql.exe`*)

The idea is that SQL server tables are stored in the app's cache .This is for - *not* to load data over and over again from the specific table.

The beauty is that Asp.net's `cache` can automatically remove the table from the `cache` (*and load it again - optionally*) when data is modified on that table.

It is done via web.config  :

```
 <system.web>
      <caching>
         <sqlCacheDependency enabled="true">
            <databases>
               <add name="Northwind" connectionStringName="AppConnectionString1" 
                pollTime="500" />
            </databases>
         </sqlCacheDependency>
      </caching>
 </system.web>
```

But the way it works is by *polling* the main sql cache Notification table (*which basically holds table names and counters*)

**Question:**

I know that service broker can be used instead . But how does the mechanism is different as opposed to polling?
I mean - when a table is changed - there is a trigger which updates the main table but how ASP.net knows that a counter (*which represent a change*) has been increased ? does ASP.net still polls ?

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/